# WooCommerce Function missing in Storefront functions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new in developing Wordpress and WooCommerce and I'm trying to customize the Storefront theme with a child theme.

For e.g., I want to delete the product search of header.php.

In header.php there's a comment:

```
* @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
```

to action 'storefront_header'

But in storefront-template-hooks.php I can't find an added action to the function 'storefront_product_search', as described before.

When I search for the function 'storefront_product_search' in storefront-template-functions.php, I also don't find it.

Where is this function located?

Another question, is there an IDE with forward navigation for php/wordpress development?

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code

Comment: search all files in the storefront folder instead of individual files

Comment: Thank you, I found it in the file "storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php". Just to be sure, why is the function in this file instead of "storefront-template-functions.php"?

Answer (score 0):

This Video Helps You - (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcwKue77uOY)

You just need to add Additional css